# AWS CLI move all files with condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, bucket

I must move into another bucket only files changed in the year 2015. How can I write this condition?

```
aws s3 mv <condition??> s3://bucket1 s3://bucket2 --recursive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly do that through through the `s3` option.
what you can do though is a 2 steps approach:

1. get the list of files that have been modified after a date

   ```
   aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket1" --query 'Contents[?LastModified > `2015-01-01`].[Key]' --output text
   ```
2. Based on this list you can move the items.

I have not tried and not an shell expert but something around this

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "<YOUR_BUCKET>" --query 'Contents[?LastModified > `2015-01-01`].[Key]' --output text | xargs aws s3 mv s3://bucket2/ -
```

Comment: Thanks ;) Have a nice day